# Bootstrap drop-down menu only works in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a drop down menu using Bootstrap, it works in Firefox but the links within the dropdown menu does not work in IE nor Chrome... any ideas?

```
<!--This is the navigation that comes up on every main pages -->
 <nav id="main_nav">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
 <li class="pads active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  <!-- Make this element the different for active -->
 <li class="pads"><a href="about.html">Portfolio</a></li>

<!--the data-toggle="dropdown" is to let the anchor toggle instead of going to another site-->
<li class="pads"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class = "dropdown-toggle" href="projects.html">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="drop_nav">
        <li><a role="menuitem" href="191stband/191stband.html">Website</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" href="agi/agi.html">AGI Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" href="workout.html">Daily Workout App</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="pads"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't get what's the problem. I tried it on jsfiddle and everything seems fine. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8567/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.  I had the CSS as follow:

`main_nav{
    z-index:1;
}`

I just need to remove the z-index property and the drop-down list works in Chrome.